# Batch or VBScript to check if Windows resolution is widescreen

Tags: screen-resolution, widescreen

I'm trying to find/write a script (existing script is a batch file, although if VBS I could always call it within batch file) that can detect if the current screen resolution is a widescreen format, so that I can copy the appropriate background image to the machine. I've only found a couple posts with the same code, and as one reply said that you can always just set the image to be stretched. But that would mean that the image could be distorted (as others have said as well).

I found the following VBScript from [this post](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/scripts/38928-vbs-detect-screen-resolution.html), although it only seems to work on Windows XP (although I haven't tried Windows 7 32-bit). In Windows 7 64 it just echos the asterick.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
 Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor where DeviceID = 'DesktopMonitor1'",,0)
 For Each objItem in colItems
 intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
 intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
 Next 

msgbox intHorizontal & " * " & intVertical
```

But even if I could get this script to work, I would still have to have multiple IF's to match the Horizontal & Vertical to a list of widescreen resolutions. Unless there's a math equation that I can use (which I'm sure there is). But regardless, I need a script that will work for both XP and 7 (32 & 64), or if need be, two scripts for each OS or architecture.

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: OK, I found my math equation. If W/H=1.33 (or 1.25 for 5:4 ratio) then aspect ratio is 4:3, otherwise it's widescreen (1.6 through 1.78). So now I just have to get a script that works for all OS's & architectures, as well as work this formula into it.

Comment: OK, so this works fine:
`If intHorizontal/IntVertical <= 1.334 then
 Aspect = "4:3"
 WScript.Echo Aspect
 Else
 Aspect = "Widescreen"
 WScript.Echo Aspect
End if`

And I've test the original code to enumerate the resolution on XP and Win7 (32 and 64) virtual machines, and they both work fine. But on my host machine (7/64) it just echo's back the "*", with no resolution. Only thing I can see that might be doing it is I do have 2 monitors. I have checked and WMI is running.

Comment: Wow, had I known I was going to find the answer so soon, I wouldn't have bothered posting this. This WMI seems to work beautifully:
`Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems 
        intHorizontal = objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution 
        intVertical = objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution 
    Next`

Comment: Can you post a complete answer and accept it?

Comment: I used this solution with Windows 10 and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for the delay, I'm not regularly on here. My last comment is the answer/solution that worked.